# Can SELinux give a regular user full control of a file system or directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, selinux

We are setting up a Linux machine (CentOS 7 to be exact) to share files within a team.  One particular regular user (the boss) will need to be able to read / write / modify / delete all files and directories in the file system or directory where we share files.  I just wonder if it is possible to set an SELinux policy to enforce his privilege.  In the past we ran a cron job to enforce permissions on all files and directories every ten minutes.  I just thought SELinux will be the better way to go if it is possible.

I am also open to any other suggestions.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably ask this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [there](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Selinux provides a mechanism for supporting access control security policies. If you need to give access to other users , you can use ACLs or file permissions.

setfacl -Rdm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir

setfacl -Rm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir

to view ACLs :- getfacl filename

u:- user

g:- group

d:- default

o:- other

see the man pages for more infor:-  man acl

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  We have been running a cron job to do "setfacl -Rm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir" every 10 minutes or so.  It enforces permissions on new files put there, and relieve less-experienced users from setting ACLs themselves.  I just wonder if SELinux may be able to do it in a more automated way.

Comment: Have you tried using d for default?  Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to

Comment: no need to set a cronjob to do this. so you can create a default rule on this shared_dir. therefore, each and every directory your going to create under this shared_dir directory will assign this privileged.

setfacl -Rdm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir

d:- Default rule. 
R:- recursively

Comment: what you have to do is run below two commands on that shared directory :- 


setfacl -Rdm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir

setfacl -Rm u:boss:rwx /shared_dir

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  The default permissions setting is a great idea.  The reason I looked into SELinux is to find a way users can't accidentally mess up the ACLs.  After some more reading, I think SELinux can't give someone permissions to access the files if the ACL doesn't allow.  I found two alternatives so the boss can be guaranteed access to the files: (1) sftp: sudo sftp-server for the boss; need to fix /etc/sudoers so he can sudo without entering password.  (2) Samba share and put him in "admin users".  I guess I will go with the second option.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. :)